# ApplicationInsights, Net core and HostBuilder (not Asp.net)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights

Can someone explain to me how to get advanced `ApplicationInsights` modules like `PerformanceCollector` working on a simple IHostService/HostBuilder .Net core application?

With a setup like this, I managed to get `ILogger` logs into ApplicationInsights:

```cs
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddLogging();

        // ApplicationInsights initializer
        services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(config => config.InstrumentationKey = "52xxxx8a-2xx2-4xx8-bxx6-4xxxxxxxxxxxx2");
        services.Configure<SamplingTelemetryProcessor>(config => config.SamplingPercentage = 10.0);
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule, DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule, PerformanceCollectorModule>();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule, AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule>();
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryProcessor, SamplingTelemetryProcessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IApplicationIdProvider, ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(configureLogging =>
    {
        configureLogging.AddConsole();
        configureLogging.AddDebug();
        configureLogging.AddApplicationInsights();
    });

builder.Build().Run();
```

But for example `PerformanceCollectorModule` is doing nothing. No performance metrics are sended.

I try to look how [Asp.Net Core Extention](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/ApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs) is working, but I don't understand it.

Packages used:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.2.0-preview" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" Version="1.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor" Version="2.3.0-preview2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="3.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.9.2" />
```

Comment: Is this a .net core web or .net core console project? and all the module do not work?

Comment: It's net core console and only ILogger works

Comment: And if possible, share us the nuget package and version you're using, the one for application insights.

Comment: I will add it later. I currently not understand who is calling modul.initialize(). Did I miss a init class?

Comment: @IvanYang I added the packaged use to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new package from Application Insights to use in non Asp.Net application as your example.
Remove all the ApplicationInsights packages you have, and just add the following one:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.8.0-beta3" />
```

Then call `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();` in your `ConfigureServices`. (remove all other application insights related code)

And modify appsettings.json with instrumentation key as below:.

```
    {
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "putinstrumentationkeyhere"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      }
    }
```

(I work in the application insights team, and this new feature is being documented officially. There will be a sample app as well once this is merged: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-home/pulls)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you always nice to see Microsoft people here answering direct. It's a bit complicated right now to follow all the different packages available for .net, .net core, asp ... You pushing new products like crazy. Like it! 

Comment: Could you also explain why my code is not working? How to init telemetry modules?

Comment: Sure. Its not working because nobody is calling telemetrymodule.Initialize() method. You can manually do var mod = new mod(); mod.Initialize(config) to make it work. In asp.net core application it works, because the SDK registers action to initialize all modules. https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Shared/Implementation/TelemetryConfigurationOptionsSetup.cs)

Comment: appreciate the feedback - we are right now polishing docs to make it clear how to onboard each of the type of app - asp.net, asp.net core, .net/.net core console app, .net core 3.0 worker services, .net 2.1/2.2 Background job/GenericHost. Your use case is the last category. The official docs will come alive before Sep 23 to align with .net core 3.0 release. (this new package above will GA then as well)

Comment: The repository now returns a 404.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service Use the docs page now that its updated